# tab1-How to sum values on column headers

Tags: r, html-table, tidyverse

I am trying to get a total number of fish caught by column using tab1. However, tab1 currently counts the number of rows on each column. Is there a way to change the columns to SUM instead of counting rows? I am aware that I can sum with "Count" at the bottom of the table but would like to sum at top instead.
See example below:

```
#Data
a <- structure(list(SampleDate = c("2012-01-13", "2012-01-13", "2012-01-13", 
"2012-01-14", "2012-01-14", "2012-01-15", "2012-01-15", "2012-01-15", 
"2012-01-15", "2012-01-15", "2012-01-15", "2012-01-15", "2012-01-15"
), FL = c(30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 170, 28, 31, 32
), Count = c(1, 2, 1, 11, 40, 40, 30, 18, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2), Turb = c(1.68, 
1.3, 2, 1.68, 1.9, 1.68, 1.68, 2.6, 1.68, 3.2, 5, 4.3, 3.5), 
    Temp = c(48.1, 48.1, 48.1, 48.1, 48.1, 48.1, 48.1, 48.1, 
    48.1, 48.1, 48.1, 48.1, 48.1), year = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 
    2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012
    ), race = c("S", "F", "LF", "W", "F", "F", "W", "F", "S", 
    "LF", "S", "W", "W")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(SampleDate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), FL = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Count = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Turb = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Temp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), race = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x0000023371ea1e30>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

SampleDate    FL Count  Turb  Temp  year race 
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1 2012-01-13    30     1  1.68  48.1  2012 S    
 2 2012-01-13    31     2  1.3   48.1  2012 F    
 3 2012-01-13    33     1  2     48.1  2012 LF   
 4 2012-01-14    34    11  1.68  48.1  2012 W    
 5 2012-01-14    35    40  1.9   48.1  2012 F    
 6 2012-01-15    36    40  1.68  48.1  2012 F    
 7 2012-01-15    37    30  1.68  48.1  2012 W    
 8 2012-01-15    38    18  2.6   48.1  2012 F    
 9 2012-01-15    39     4  1.68  48.1  2012 S    
10 2012-01-15   170     1  3.2   48.1  2012 LF   
11 2012-01-15    28     1  5     48.1  2012 S    
12 2012-01-15    31     3  4.3   48.1  2012 W    
13 2012-01-15    32     2  3.5   48.1  2012 W 

    # Code
    a$SampleDate <- as.Date(a$SampleDate,"%m/%d/%Y")

a$SampleDate <- as.character(a$SampleDate)
table1(~ SampleDate + Temp + Turb + FL + Count | race, data = a, caption= "Preliminary estimates",
       render.continuous=c(.="Min", .="Mean", .="Max"))

#The desired output should be after adding each column:
F  N(100)
S  N(6)
LF N(2)
W  N(46)
```

[image]